# Redirecting to the same controller method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters

Assume, there's a standard books_controller where I need to modify index method. If params[:value] is nil I need to assign not_nil value to it and then reload the same page. What I do within index method is

```
redirect = params[:value].nil?
params[:value] ||= some_value_which_is_not_nil
redirect_to books_path if redirect
```

The problem is that after redirecting the params[:value] is nil again! How can I pass params variable to the redirect_to method or is there any other way to store this value?

Comment: You shouldn't have to redirect to the same page.  The controller action will complete before the page is actually rendered, so setting the variable the first request will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The `params` hash doesn't work that way. HTTP is stateless - assignments won't persist across requests.

What this means is, the `params` hash is populated from the GET/POST parameters in the request each time a request is made. If you want to redirect to the same page and have that parameter persist, you must pass it as a GET parameter.

```
redirect_to books_path(:value => some_value_which_is_not_nil) if redirect
```

Comment: so what's the solution? instance variables?

Comment: No, persisting data across requests is done with cookies or some server side backing store. In this case, you can simply add the value as a parameter to the request. However, in the future you'll find yourself wanting to pass whole objects from request to request. This gets messy. You can either store the object in the cookie (4KB limit), which is not encrypted, or tie the user's session to a database, memcache, or some other backing store.

Comment: To further clarify, consider the fact that two sequential requests to your application could quite possibly be handled by two completely separate running instances of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're looking for but you can pass parameters into `path` methods.

`books_path(:value => 1)` results in `/books?value=1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
 ## RELOAD same page if params value is nil
 params[:value] || redirect_to books_path(:value => "some_value_which_is_not_nil")
 # Do my own processing!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the nil value to something it should be in the same action that you're going to reload ... why not just continue processing with the value you set without reloading?

I can't see that you need to reload the action at all.